# Two Knex queries (node.js) and one of it - in forEach loop

Tags: node.js, select, foreach, knex.js

One table is UserChats with list of chats-to-users.
The other table is ChatList with all chats.

I need to build an array of chats of a specific user into variable and return it.

```
_DB("UserChats").select('*').where({
 
  uID: user_id
 
}).then(chats => {
 
  const userChats = []
 
  chats.forEach(chat => {
 
    _DB('ChatList').where({
 
      id: chat.chatID
 
    }).select('*').then(chat_data => {
 
      userChats.push(chat_data);
 
    });
 
  });

 return userChats; // but this variable is empty

});
```

How can I elegantly rewrite the code so that all the code is executed?

The join query will be as follows:

```
_DB('UserChats')
.select('*')
.where({ "UserChats.uID": user_id })
.join('ChatList', 'UserChats.chatID', 'ChatList.id')
.then(function(rows) {
  return rows;
});
```

Comment: Share data base structure and just a question can't you apply a  join on tables?

Comment: @DhruvPal ChatList: id, chatName; UserChats: chatID, uID, roleID. Can't use join, because I have simplified the logic model, in reality I will need some more actions in each forEach.

Comment: please update the question with table structure and what is the action that u are performing I can't see that. If you add these I can have better visibility

Comment: @DhruvPal In one table there is a list of chats. Another table stores data about which users participate in which chats. We need to make a selection for a specific user, in which chats he participates and define all this in a variable.